# Is there any way to get button answer without interactive message?

Tags: button, message, slack-api

We're implementing a slackbot internally in our company.

Because we cannot open a local server on internet, we want to bypass interactive message system.
Is there any way to do so ? A custom event for example ?

Thanks,

Yohann.

Answer (score 1):

No, that is not possible.

And frankly, you can not use much of Slack's functionality without exposing your app to the Internet, so that Slack can interact with it.

But there are ways to expose your app to the Internet, without compromising the security of your company network. One way is to use a secure tunnel to your "localhost". A service provided by companies like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/).

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44726440/4379151) to a similar problem.