# Slack slash command with local web service

Tags: slack, slack-dialog

I put a local web service (started with 10.xx) in the `Request URL` section of a Slack slash command setting.
When invoking in the channel, it gives me `503_service_error`.

Our company is using Slack, and I'm in one of its workspaces, Is there any workaround that this workspace can access a private IP.

PS: the URL I configured is accessible from my desktop.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to integrate internal APIs (Not accessible outside office network) to slack slash commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44726200/how-to-integrate-internal-apis-not-accessible-outside-office-network-to-slack)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

slack can not access your local network. You have to use some type of http/https tunneling software or router forwarding. We are using ngrok.com for this (as is also recommended by the slack team)

ngrok will gibe you a domain that will point to your desktop computer which you have to configure in your slack app